# How to add salt to AES Encryption/Decryption?

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes

I had a previously asked question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68363423/aes-encryption-in-java-working-but-decryption-in-javascript-not-working/68365135?noredirect=1#comment120882159_68365135) about implementing encryption in Java and decrypting using CryptoJS. I was advised in the comments of that question to implement some sort of key derivation function instead of directly using a "secret". This was also advised in my CheckMarx report to use salt to make the encryption more secure. This is how I'm encrypting from the Java side, concatenating the bytes of myKey and the salt:

```
package aes;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
 
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AesEncryption {

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;
 
    public static void setKey(String myKey) {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            byte[] salt = generateSalt(16);
            key = Bytes.concat(myKey.getBytes(), salt);
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); 
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) {
        try {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    private static byte[] generateSalt(int length) {
        Random r = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[length];
        r.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }
}
```

The trouble I am having now is how to correctly decrypt with newly added salt. This is the decrypt function called from the JavaScript side:

```
aesDecrypt: (encryptedValue, aesSecret) => {
        var sha1Hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(aesSecret)
        var secretAesKey = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(sha1Hash.words.slice(0, 16 / 4));
        var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedValue, secretAesKey, {
          mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
          padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        })
        var originalValue = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        return originalValue
}
```

How can I derive just the secretAesKey from the byte array now that the salt is added?

Comment: You have to use the same salt

Comment: Is that a common thing to pass salt in a payload? @g00se

Comment: Yes, it's pretty common

Comment: Is there anything extra I would need to add to the decrypt function logically to make it work besides that? @g00se Still fairly new to encryption.

Comment: Why don't you use a reliable key derivation function like PBKDF2, which was designed specifically for this purpose. This is more secure than a digest (even with salt). Also, SHA1 and ECB are not secure choices.

Comment: Do you have an in depth example you can point to? @user9014097

Comment: You can find many examples on the web, e.g. [Java/SCEE](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples/blob/master/Java/SCEE.java). This solution uses besides PBKDF2 also a secure mode in combination with a random IV/nonce.

Comment: I see! I appreciate it! Is CryptoJS advised to use to decrypt from the JavaScript side or is there a better solution? @user9014097

Comment: CryptoJS doesn't support the GCM mode. But the link offers cross-platform implementations, also for JavaScript and various JavaScript-libraries (SJCL, WebCrypto API, NodeJS), s. [here](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples/tree/master/JavaScript). If you want to use CryptoJS, you have to change the mode to e.g. CBC. Authentication must then be implemented by yourself (e.g. with a MAC).

Comment: >Is there anything extra I would need to add to the decrypt function logically to make it work besides that? <
I'm unfamiliar with that JavaScript stuff so can't say.

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption for how `openssl enc` derives a key from a password and handles the salt, and see https://github.com/meixler/web-browser-based-file-encryption-decryption for an equivalent implementation in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple principial issues in your solution:

```
        byte[] salt = generateSalt(16);
        key = Bytes.concat(myKey.getBytes(), salt);
      ... 
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

> How can I derive just the secretAesKey from the byte array now that the salt is added?

The breaking mistake in your code is that you are creating a random key (concatenate or a random salt and a password). There is no way you could recover the original value. The salt is random for encryption, but needs to be known for decryption.

Second point I'd like to address is using the ECB mode. Try to read and understand different [mode of operations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).  The EBC mode is effectively using only a key (no salt/IV) and this mode has several inherited weaknesses, I'd really suggest to use other modes (CBC, GCM,..).

There are two random inputs for encryption:

- salt for a password, try to search for KDF (PBKDF2, BCrypt, SCrypt, Argon2) where you generate an encryption key from the password. Using a simple hash may not be good enough way to create an encryption key from a password.
- IV (initialization vector) ensuring unique and unpredictable combination of plaintext and key. If you have a random password salt resulting into a random encryption key, then the IV can be static.

**These random values (IV or salt) are encryption parameters needed for decryption, so the values are usually passed along the ciphertext and not needing to be secret.**

If you want to return a single encoded string, then youcan try to create something like `salt|ciphertext|mac`. See [some examples](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) for  Password symmetric encryption.

I'm not so proficient in JS so I leave the details to find up to you, but you need to use the same parameters and values in both languages